# How to test setter in subscribe? angular

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, setter, subscribe

I have this code:

```
    public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300), this.takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(query => {
      this.officeService.searchQuery = query;
    });
  }
```

How to coverage **searchQuery** setter?

I wrote test who pass, but not coverage setter.

My test:

```
it('should searchQuery called ', () => {
    const { component, service } = setup();
    const query: string = 'test';
    const fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const inputEvent = new Event('input');
    const spiez: jasmine.Spy = spyOnProperty(service, 'searchQuery', 'set');

    component.searchControl.valueChanges.subscribe((tmp: string) => expect(spiez).toHaveBeenCalledWith(tmp));
    input.nativeElement.value = 'newString';
    input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

My test with **fakeAsync** and **tick**:

```
    const { component, service } = setup();
    const query: string = 'test';
    const fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const inputEvent = new Event('input');
    const spiez: jasmine.Spy = spyOnProperty(service, 'searchQuery', 'set');

    component.searchControl.valueChanges.subscribe((tmp: string) => expect(spiez).toHaveBeenCalledWith(tmp));
    input.nativeElement.value = 'newString';
    input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick(300);
  }));
```

Comment: By modifying the value of the search control inside a fakeAsync test and ticking 300ms: https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync

Comment: @JBNizet check edit. Like that?

Comment: No. subscribing in your test is useless. You already subscribe in your component, and it's that subscription that should, **after 300ms** set the property. So your check that the property is set should be **after** the call to tick(300).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
    describe('SearchComponent', () => {
      let component: SearchComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ SearchComponent ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should test value changes', () => {
        const testValue = 'test';
        const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
        const spiez: jasmine.Spy = spyOnProperty(service, 'searchQuery');
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges()
        input.nativeElement.value = testValue;
        dispatchEvent(input.nativeElement, "input");
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(spiez).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testValue))
      }));
```

Comment: I have a error:


```Error: Expected spy searchQuery to have been called with:
   [ 'test' ]
 but it was never called.
```

Comment: There I updated muy asnwer. Please, try now to see if it's works.

Comment: The same error. I tried everything, and I don't know :D

Comment: Do not worry, we will keep trying until the test works!!!
I have just updated my answer, try it now